# in BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION structure what is nNumberOfLinks

Tags: winapi, ntfs

in the doc, they have mentioned that nNumberOfLinks is "The number of links to this file. For the FAT file system, this member is always 1. For the NTFS file system, it can be more than 1."

The number of links to the file means what ? if that file used as the destination of 3 symlinks then nNumberOfLinks is 3 . or it has some other meaning.

Comment: That counts only the hardlinks, not symlinks, though I don't have an authoritative source offhand to quote.

Comment: The symlink is implemented by a reparse point, Functions like `GetFileAttributes` and `FindFirstFile` could provide information about a symbolic link. The file attributes will have the `FILE_ATTRIBUTES_REPARSE_POINT` flag set, and the `dwReserved0` member will contain the special value `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK`. refer to [How do I get information about the target of a symbolic link?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100212-00/?p=14963)

Comment: As test result: if that file used only as the destination of 3 symlinks, then nNumberOfLinks is 1(the file itself). if that file used as the destination of 3 hardlinks, then nNumberOfLinks is 4(3+1). [`CreateHardLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createhardlinka#remarks) also metioned that: *When you create a hard link on the NTFS file system, the file attribute information in the directory entry is refreshed only when the file is opened, or when GetFileInformationByHandle is called with the handle of a specific file.*

Comment: Hi @simplePerson43, Did the post answer your question? You could feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if it did help.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the implementation of GetFileInformationByHandle in the ReactOS source code,
https://doxygen.reactos.org/da/d02/dll_2win32_2kernel32_2client_2file_2fileinfo_8c_source.html We can see the field nNumberOfLinks gets populated as follows (error checking removed).

```
errCode = NtQueryInformationFile(hFile,
                &IoStatusBlock,
                &FileStandard,
                sizeof(FILE_STANDARD_INFORMATION),
                FileStandardInformation);
lpFileInformation->nNumberOfLinks = FileStandard.NumberOfLinks;
```

As per the documentation of FILE_STANDARD_INFORMATION https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_standard_information.

> NumberOfLinks

> The number of hard links to the file.

So nNumberOfLinks will be the number of hard links, as mentioned by dxiv in the comments.